# LinkedIn Follow button plugin is opening a blank window

Tags: linkedin-api

Using LinkedIn's site that creates the scripts for plugins, I created the plugin with the following script:

```
<script src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="2922419" data-counter="top"></script>
```

I tried different things; with the https, without it (as they posted), but whenever I click on the button, it just opens up a blank window. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

it is not a big issue if LinkedIn Script is not working fine then just add your own onclick redirect url.i-e `onclick="window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/company/{companyID}/');"` and then  add `style="pointer-events:none;"` css to its child(i.e LinkedIN scripts) to make its default behavior overridden.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried including the URL with your button? E.g:

```
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="2922419" data-counter="top" data-url="www.yourdomain.com/path/to/your/page"></script>
```

Replace the link with the page you want to share.